# TensorFlow Object detection API only in specified region of frame (defining ROI in input frame)

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, tensorflow2.0, object-detection

I am using TensorFlow Object Detection API (https://github.com/tensorflow/models) for custom object detection.
I have trained my model on custom object detection, and the result is good.

**Now I want to define a region in my input frame, i,e only in this defined region my object detection should be working. The object detected outside the region of interest should be ignored.**

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('video.mp4') 

def run_inference(model, cap):
    while cap.isOpened():
        ret, image_np = cap.read()
        # Actual detection.
        output_dict = run_inference_for_single_image(model, image_np)
        # Visualization of the results of detection.
        vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
            image_np,
            output_dict['detection_boxes'],
            output_dict['detection_classes'],
            output_dict['detection_scores'],
            category_index,
            instance_masks=output_dict.get('detection_masks_reframed', None),
            use_normalized_coordinates=True,
            line_thickness=8)
        cv2.imshow('object_detection', cv2.resize(image_np, (800, 600)))
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            cap.release()
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break

run_inference(detection_model, cap)
```

I have tried using  cv2 function polylines to define lines on my input frames.

```
cv2.polylines(image, [pts], isClosed, color, thickness)
```

**but couldn't activate object detection API to work only in the specified region**

**Expected Final Output:** In the video frame I should a polygon box representing as Region of Interest(ROI) and whenever objected is detected inside the ROI it should give me bounding boxes (outside this ROI, it can neglect)

Answer (score 0):

`cv2.polylines()` is just for drawing lines on the image, it's merely a visual thing.

You can crop the numpy image `image_np` by the region you want, and pass that cropped img to `tf`.

```
image_cropped = image_np[y_start:y_end, x_start:x_end]
```

What is a bit unintuitive is that when a image is represented with numpy, the first index is 'y axis', and second index is 'x axis'.

Comment: cropping an image and passing it to TF is not an ideal way for my solution. i want to visually show the region of interest in the frame and detect object only in that specified region

Comment: I mean you can detect the object from the cropped image, and still show the region of interest in the original image. I.E. just get the information you need from the cropped image and show the information on the original image.

Comment: Ideally this should be part of the results you draw on those images right? This has nothing to do with open cv. This should be part of `vis_util` and the results you get `output_dict['detection_boxes']`

Comment: @papaya Yes. in the video frame, I should show the region of interest (ROI) any whenever objected is detected inside the ROI it should give me bounding boxes

Comment: What is stopping you from filtering out from the bboxes.